# Can't access to Cloud9 IDE running on a Google Compute Engine - Ubuntu 14.04.02

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to run cloud9 IDE on a Google Compute Engine instance running Ubuntu 14.04.02,
but i can't have access to the IDE through a web browser typing the `<external_ip>:<port>`.
I allowed access to tcp ports 80, 8080 and 8181.
Then followed the cloud9 core [tutorial](https://github.com/c9/core). The server is currently running in port 8080 :
`@devinstance:~/c9sdk$ node server.js -p 8080
Authentication is required when not running on localhost.
Please use -a user:pass or --listen localhost to listen locally.
switching to localhost
Connect server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8080
CDN: version standalone initialized /home/augustin_bessette_gmail_com/c9sdk/build
Started '/home/augustin_bessette_gmail_com/c9sdk/configs/standalone' with config 'standalone'!`
I can see that my server is running on the port 8080 using :
`lsof -i tcp:8080
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    1901     -   12u  IPv4  12209      0t0  TCP localhost:http-alt (LISTEN)`
or
`netstat -an | grep ":8080"
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

I you have any idea of the issue, any help would be much appreciated :) !

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not providing a username/password with the `-a` argument Cloud9 is running on `localhost` for security reasons. You need to configure authentication to run Cloud9 on a public IP address.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I actually tryed  
`node server.js --auth <user_login>:<password> --port 8080`  
but it doesn't work...

Comment: I just started a node.js server instance through hapiJs which worked on my cloud9 account, and it fails too... So i guess that the problem comes from my google engine instance ... But tcp 80, 8080, 8181 are open :'(

Comment: I'm able to connect to the web page through my cellphone, but not through my laptop using the school wifi ...